# Unknown Errors in Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a HTML/JS/CSS script that counts the number of days until some birthdays.

Last year, I made one, it still works, I copied and pasted the same script, and changed the names/dates and now it doesn't work.

Working one: http://jsbin.com/iFItOYo/16/edit

Broken one: http://jsbin.com/iFItOYo/14/edit

Comment: your code is a mess. You should indent it, close brackets and tags. Please clean it up before you post it here.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, you are missing the the closing tag of the comment '-->', and thus you get an unexpected end of input error.

Also putting your script inside of a comment is not such a good practice, use [cross browser CSS if comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Also, use [indenting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), and lower case HTML, with [indenting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) as well.

In addition, your script tag is not valid in any HTML \ XHTML spec.

Hope this helps.

Another issue: 
`<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">` which comes after the h3 opening tag is also missing.

Perhaps this question belongs to code review.

Answer (score 1):

You made a couple of mistakes:

You forgot the closing bracket at this point:

```
  fatima = new Date(thisYr,2,7)
    if (fatima.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
      fatima.setYear(nextYr)
    }  <-- this one is missing
```

In the beginning you state `now = new Date`, which should be `now = new Date()`

You forgot to close the `<!--` that you begin in the top of your code

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the `<script ...>` tag right after the opening `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of mistakes in your code. You should do something to view it clearly so that you can see your mistake easily like indent code, write all in lowercase (both javascript and html), comment and closing code more exactly...

To fix the one not run you must do these 3 points:

1 Like koenp answer, closing this :

```
falisha = new Date(thisYr,2,20)
if (falisha.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
falisha.setYear(nextYr)
} <== add this bracket
```

2 Missing the script tag before calling the document write function in body

```
<H3>The following are the numbers of days until class birthdays (2011-12):
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"> <== add this
```

3 Wrong variable in this line

```
if (anahi.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
anihi.setYear(nextYr)  <== change it to anahi (of course)
}
```